# What is the purpose of using getters and setters in angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am new to angular2 and when i was reviewing someone's code, one specific line got me confused

```
get formData() { return <FormArray>this.lienHolder.get('policyDetails'); }
```

why is the above line any different from this

```
formData() { return <FormArray>this.lienHolder.get('policyDetails'); }
```

I searched about this in google and found no actual results, can anyone help me to understand this.

**UPDATE**

what is the difference between this

```
var obj = { log: 0, get latest() { return this.log++; } };
```

and this

```
var obj = { log: 0, latest() { return this.log++; } };
```

both are giving me the updated value all the time i call them
obj.latest & obj.latest() -- returns updated result all the time then why use one over another?

Comment: Really, the only difference is the ability to use the assignment operator to set the data and the dot operator to get the data, as opposed to having to call functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
get formData()
```

is called a **getter** accessor. It allows you get the property dynamically. It always should return a value.

---

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

> TypeScript supports getters/setters as a way of intercepting accesses
>   to a member of an object. This gives you a way of having finer-grained
>   control over how a member is accessed on each object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

> Sometimes it is desirable to allow access to a property that returns a
>   dynamically computed value, or you may want to reflect the status of
>   an internal variable without requiring the use of explicit method
>   calls. In JavaScript, this can be accomplished with the use of a
>   getter.

---

In opposite to that, `getFormDate()` is a **function**, it can take arguments and not always returns values.

One of the cases, where I like to use a getter is when a property should be get from a service:

```
<p>{{dictionary.label1}}</p>
```

and then  I get it from a service like this:

```
get dictionary(){
  return this.myService.getDictionary();
}
```

this way when the service changed the data I dynamically can receive the value to my binding/model.

If I would have defined as the following:

```
dictionary: [];

ngOnInit(){
  this.dictionary = this.myService.getDictionary();
}
```

then I would be 'stuck' with the old data while the service already received the new set of data. Of course, you can then set a change listener and trigger the update, but it's more code!

**Think of getters as dynamic class properties.**

---

**UPDATE:**

For the examples in your updated post, it's true, they give the same result, and it's a good thing! You can use both, but as they don't work similarly, you can have more options in some cases. It's not like only one or only the other, or which one is the best. In most of cases you can use both, it's where and for what you need to use them. Most of the times, it's a method which is used, as it has more comprehensive use: we use methods with or without parameters, to trigger actions on objects. But in some cases, again, it will not have the same flexibility as a getter. If you are hesitant which one to use, use the method first and when you see its limits, think if the getter would help you, as now you know what's its purpose, which is - a property, but dynamic!

---

**An other example:**

```
isShown:boolean; //is 'static', will return the same value unless you change it in some kind of a method

get isShown(){
   return this.someCondition && this.someMethodResult() || this.anotherCondition
}
```

If someCondition and anotherCondition change and the result from someMethodResult had to come changed you don't have to request isShown value, it's done dynamically.

Opposite of that, you can have

```
setShown(){ //the method
  this.isShow = !this.isShown;
}
```

Here setShown needs to be called so isShown could be updated.

**Also, a getter can easily replace a method which only job is to return a class property value.**

---

**UPDATE2:**

An other 'good' example for `get`. A case when a component needs to check if the user is logged to show/hide some buttons. Instead of subscribing to changes, you do:

HTML:

```
<button [hidden]="!isLogged">Log out</button>
```

Typescript:

```
get isLoggedIn(){
   return this.authService.isLoggedIn();
}
```

And that's it! If the user is logged out the button will be disabled 'immediatly'. No nead for the heavy subscribe/unsubscribe...

Comment: why is get so different from the normal method?
a=0;
function incr(){
return a++;
};

Comment: i can achieve the same functionality using a normal method, why is the getter so different?

Comment: The other very important thing to note here is that if an element in the HTML is bound to the property, the getter will be re-executed every time the change detection sees that the value changes. So if you need to write any code on "value changes" you can do it by simply adding that code to the getter.

Comment: what is the difference between this
var obj = {
  log: 0,
  get latest() {
        return this.log++;
  }
};
and this
var obj = {
  log: 0,
  latest() {
        return this.log++;
  }
};
both are giving me the updated value all the time i call them

Answer (score 1):

with the `get` you can treat it like a var:

```
let something = formData;
```

otherwise you must invoke the function:

```
let something = formData();
```

You would use a `get` usually to format data as you retrieve it. for example:

```
let _number = '12';
get number(){
  return parseInt(_number);
}
```