# What is the advantage of using get/set accessors instead of standard getter/setter methods?

Tags: typescript

Coming from Java it feels more natural to write a class this way:

```
class Person1 {

    private name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

According to http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ this gets transpiled to fairly easy ES5 code:

```
var Person1 = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Person1(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    Person1.prototype.getName = function () {
        return this.name;
    };
    return Person1;
}());
```

However, the [official documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) uses the keyword `get` & `set` like this:

```
class Person2 {

    private _name: string;
    constructor(name: string) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }
}
```

Which gets transpiled to this:

```
var Person2 = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Person2(name) {
        this._name = name;
    }
    Object.defineProperty(Person2.prototype, "name", {
        get: function () {
            return this._name;
        },
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    });
    return Person2;
}());
```

Are there technical advantages in the resulting ES5 code?

Thanks!

Comment: Could this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45760862/5468463

Comment: @Vega Thanks. I learned from your answer that `get` and `set` do enforce to adhere the expected getter & setter interface, which is a good thing, but I struggle to see the advantage, because these methods are so common in OOP. My question was more about the technical advantages of the resulting ES5 code. I will specify this in my question, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question isn't really a good fit for stackoverflow as any answers you get are bound to be largely based on opinion, however:

There are several reasons why public attributes are preferred over getter and setter methods, these include the cleaner syntax, and also the reduced boilerplate as you don't have to declare getter and setter methods. Also, in Javascript or Typescript you are likely to be using plain objects quite often, so for example:

```
type IPerson = {
  name: string
};

class Person implements IPerson {
  constructor (public name: string) {};
}

function greet(person: IPerson) {
  console.log(`Hello ${person.name}`);
}

greet(new Person('Napoleon'));
greet({name: 'Snowball'});
```

Now if you actually need to do something fancy when the attribute is accessed (or updated), you can have a class with `get`/`set` on the attribute:

```
class Person2 implements IPerson {
  constructor(private _firstname: string, private _lastname: string) {
  }

  get name(): string {
      return `${this._firstname} ${this._lastname}`;
  }
}

greet(new Person2('Old', 'Major'))
```

But the important thing to remember is that you would not define `get` and `set` if the only thing they do is access a private attribute, there's just no reason to do that.

Using getters and setters is only prevalent in languages like Java where it is the only option to protect access to attributes on objects. In other languages which support `get` and `set` properties it is much more common to simply expose attributes as public. Then if required you can change the class definitions later to use `get` and `set`, but only if you need it. Changing the implementation this way does not require any change to the code which uses the class.

This is the important distinction: in Java if you need to change from a public attribute to a computed property you would have to change the declared interface affecting everything that uses the class, so you avoid ever exposing attributes as public. In typescript and most other languages only the class implementation changes, not the exposed interface.