# *ngIf directive assigned with the help of a method returning boolean value or having the logic within HTML, which is better?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have come across scenarios where we need to display a view based on some conditions. Is it a good practice to show with the help of a method/function returning Boolean value? For example:

HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="showUserDetails()">User Details</div>
```

TS:

```
private user:User;
public showUserDetails(): boolean{
  return (this.user!=null && this.user !=undefined);
}
```

This is just an example. In the scenarios that I have, there are lot of logic within the method. So could someone suggest if this approach is good or not.

Comment: In my opinion, the best course of action would be to set up a variable and have that variable updated each time the data related to it changes. Alternately, you may switch your detection approach to "onPush" and continue using the function that way. The function would only be called in this case if the component has undergone changes. But the catch is that you have to manually account for some of the component changes when using "onPush."

Answer (score 1):

While you are able to call functions directly from your template, the prevailing view is that for performance reasons this should be avoided - see [this article](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496) for more info and some alternative approaches.

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49301176/2627160) and taking the example in your original question, I'd just make `user` public and do:

```
<div *ngIf="!!user">User Details</div>
```

But another good point made in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49301176/2627160), is that the "right" approach will be largely opinion based.

Comment: Using getters and setters, in my opinion, is essentially the same because they are both methods. And if you add a debugger to the getter, you'll actually notice that it hits a very high number of times. Therefore, if your getter contains a lot of logic, you would essentially be invoking a function.

Comment: You're absolutely right @KZoeps - was just updating my answer!